# cannot import name 'configure_inline_support' from 'ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have these line in my jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But I am getteing this error:

```
 cannot import name 'configure_inline_support' from 'ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

It was working yesterday before I update VSC to the latest version.

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you switched the Python kernel used in Jupyter?
Please check whether the kernel dependency "ipykernel" and the required modules have been installed in the currently used python kernel.